# See who last changed category color on outlook email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba

Here is the situation. Someone at work in a shared inbox keeps changing the category on incoming email to a specific color. For this shared inbox those colors represent the employee who has picked up that email request and is working the request. The problem is no one is fessing up to who is changing the email category and its affecting workflow.

Question:

Is there a way to view who changed a category on an email. Maybe some VBA code to inspect the metadata or some option I am not able to find in outlook?

Comment: such a thing is most likely impossible, unless you start  keeping a log of changes. Even that log of changes may be missing some things, assuming multiple actions are taken between updates of your local copy of the inbox. The proper solution here is to invest in a real ticketing system

Comment: To reinforce what Vogel just said: I had a look at the properties of a `MailItem` and didn't find anything remotely interesting for you in this case. There is a field `Categories` that can contain category names (which in turn correspond to colors) and a field `LastModificationDate` but that's about all. To get more detailed info, you'd need to set up events to log what you want to know. And as mentioned, if the poll rate is set to low, some things might slip your attention.

Comment: (@Vogel612, @Inarion) Thanks for the info. We may be able to look into a ticketing system later. We still have the problem of knowing who is changing things when they shouldn't be. Oh well was worth asking just in case I missed something in my research on it.